# Form cannot be displayed dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I trying to build a method to draw my form dynamically, this method receives a list of questions, from this we draw a form and show each question (label) and an option (yes/no - radio buttons).
I can add each control created before in my Forms.Controls, but when the form opens, just one question is rendered passing a list with more than 20 questions. Why? Did I forget to do something?

[image: form]

This method builds all my components to the form based on my list of questions.

```
private void BuildComponents(List<Question> properties)
        {
            this.propertyList = new List<System.Windows.Forms.Control>();

            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
            {
                var newLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label
                {
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13 + i + 5, 13),
                    Name = properties[i].Label,
                    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(699, properties[i].Description.Length),
                    TabIndex = i,
                    Text = properties[i].Description,
                };

                var newYesRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
                {
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13 + i + 5, 34),
                    Name = "radioButton" + i + 1,
                    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(52, 21),
                    TabIndex = i + 1,
                    TabStop = true,
                    Text = "Sim",
                    UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
                };

                var newNoRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
                {
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(71 + i + 5, 34),
                    Name = "radioButton" + i + 2,
                    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 21),
                    TabIndex = i + 1,
                    TabStop = true,
                    Text = "Não",
                    UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
                };

                propertyList.Add(newLabel);
                propertyList.Add(newYesRadioButton);
                propertyList.Add(newNoRadioButton);
            };
        }
```

This method initializes my form and add all properties built in this.Controls

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   this.BuildComponents(questions);

            foreach (var property in propertyList)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(property);
            }
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to debug your code to check where it goes wrong...Start with the List you store your objects..do you actually have 60 objects

Comment: For the reason why it soesn't work, indeed do use the debugger! -  For general advice I would create a UserControl with a label and two radiobuttons and a constructor that takes a string and a bool. Then Add instances of it to a FlowLayoutPanel! This would be much easier to extend..

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use FlowLayoutPanel and UserControls. With FlowLayoutPanel you can put usercontrols one after another and you dont need to deal with the location property.

In addition, you should not change InitializeComponent..
Actually, you dont need to touch the code in the designer file!